# __vectorcall via C++/CLI or PInvoke (C#)

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, pinvoke, calling-convention

Is there any way to invoke C++ functions that use the __vectorcall calling convention via PInvoke or C++/ CLI? So far my attempts have suggested this is not possible (yet). Figured I would ask here to see if anyone knew of a creative way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a forwarding function in C++ that takes its arguments in the normal way (cdecl), then forwards those on to the function that expects them in __vectorcall.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke `__vectorcall` with p/invoke but you can using C++/CLI.

There's nothing special about doing so from C++/CLI. The C++ compiler has support, you can simply declare functions with this calling convention and call them.

Comment: I get a compiler warning when a __vectorcall function is declared with /clr. It just converts the function to __stdcall: https://i.gyazo.com/7bdf18d6078a9ac327b269a7f0f90d50.png

Comment: You can't use vector call in a managed function but it should be fine in an unmanaged one.